# DIsable JFace TextCellEditor Field

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

Anyone know if it's possible to enable/disable individual JFace TextCellEditor fields.

For instance if I have a table with 5 columns, I want the last cell to be empty unless field #4 is filled in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the EditingSupport class, you can set `canEdit` to return true.

```
TableViewerColumn column = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE); 

EditingSupport editingSupport = new EditingSupport(viewer) 
{
    ... implement abstract methods ...

    protected boolean canEdit(Object element)
    {
        return (/* criteria to determine if this column is editable*/)
    } 
}; 

column.setEditingSupport(editingSupport);
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be what I need. Will be trying this today...hope I can check that green checkbox for you

Comment: I ended up doing it a bit different by making a CellModifier that implements ICellModifier

Just wish I could find something better than canEdit - like actually grey out the field

Comment: @PSU_Kardi : I am facing similar problem. I tried with EditingSupport. But I want to be like greying out the entire row. Can you please give me some idea if u have done it?